# Why is DateTime.now returning 'invalid date'?

Tags: ruby, datetime

In a haml partial I have:

=@date = DateTime.now

and it's returning' invalid date':

/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date.rb:809:in `civil'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/Date.rb:1810:in`now'

Any ideas why?

Comment: I wonder if you want `Time.now` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=@date = Time.now
```